# Use the laws of logic to prove that the following is a tautology?

Tags: logic

I know that the right way is to use the implication reduction law. Though, I do not seem to get to a point where I prove that it's a tautology.

[(p → q) ∧ (q → r)] → (p → r)

Comment: There is no universal consensus on what the "laws of logic" are, and hopefully there never will be.  In some logics, a truth table is sufficient.  In others, you can't even assume demorgans or double negation.  You'll have to specify which logic you are using, since the obvious approach of "truth table" seems to have been avoided.

Answer (score 1):

You can prove it with Natural Deduction :

*1)* assume $(p \rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow r)$

*2)* derive both $(p \rightarrow q)$ and $(q \rightarrow r)$ using $\land$-elim

*3)* assume $p$ and derive $q$ from 2a) by $\rightarrow$-elim

*4)* with $q$ derive $r$ from 2b) by $\rightarrow$-elim

*5)* derive $(p \rightarrow r)$ from 3) and 4) by $\rightarrow$-intro, discharging assumption $p$ of 3)

*6)* derive $( (p \rightarrow q) \land (q \rightarrow r) ) \rightarrow (p \rightarrow r)$ from 1) and 5) discharging the assumption in 1).

Now, using *soundness* of propositional calculus (i.e. every theorem of the calculus is a *tautology*), from the above proof we can conclude that the formula in 6) is a tautology.